# How many methods could be used to solve this optimization problem with equality constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I wonder whether there is a simplest method for this problem.

The function to maximize is $F(x)$.
$F(x)=\|Kx\|_2^2=x^TK^TKx$, where $K\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

and $\nabla F=2K^TKx.$

The equality constraints are
$$g(x_i)=1-|x_i|=0,i=1,\cdots,d$$where $x_i$ is the $i^{th}$ component of $x$.

I try to use Lagrange multiplier, but it ends a uncomputable problem.

I figure out a method but I am not sure this will work well.

I can use gradient increase to solve the follow equation.

$$x^TK^TKx-(x_1-1)^2-\cdots-(x_d-1)^2$$

I am looking forward to your advice.

Comment: Note that your equality constraint is equal to $x_i \in \{-1, 1\}$. Hence, your optimization problem belongs to _discrete optimization_ and you will not have success using _continuous optimization_ methods like steepest descent.

Comment: @gerw, hello, thank you for your comment. Discrete optimiization is quite new to me. Could you recommend me a good book or paper?

Comment: @Vivian I see that you haven't accepted any of your previous question's answers. It might be a good idea to accept answers if you feel they are worth it. It is a small token of gratitude from you for the time people in MSE invest in answering your questions.

Comment: @dineshdileep, OMG, is there a such thing? I do not know how to accept the answer. I try to gratitude the people who answer my question by clicking the up arrow. Thank you for reminding me. I will check how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am curious to know where you apply this. I am familiar with this problem from the context of wireless sensor networks. This problem belongs to the class of non-convex combinatorial quadratic programming and is NP-Hard. A well-known numerical approximation technique is semi-definite relaxation. Please read this [well-known paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5447068) to know more about it.